# Area calculation of objects with the same, specific formulation

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, calculate-values

Can someone help me with the area calculation of certain objects in the attribute table?

I want to add up all the objects that follow a specific, same formulation of a specific column in the table. I have a large number of owners who in turn own many areas/objects. Now I want to see how much total area each owner has.

I can calculate every object of a certain column. But how does the formulation in the field calculator have to look like if I want to add up all those from column x that have the same formulation?

Answer (score 3):

If you've got a vector layer with one attribute for the area ("SUPERFICIE" in my example) and another attribute for grouping the data ("ZONIFICACI" in my example)

[image]

You can use the "Statistics by categories" tool in the toolbox, selecting the layer; the field (attribute) for which you want the statistics ("SUPERFICIE" in my example); and the field with the categories (clicking the 3 dots button on the right and checking the corresponding field)

[image]

Click `execute` and you'll get a new layer with the statistics, being the sum (of the area in this example) one of the values

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`sum($area,group_by:="fieldname containing owners")` it is.

For more details check the documentation page on [sum](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=sum#sum).